# Run Multiple commands in a single line in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

When I execute the following commands separately i can get the information of the mnc file

```
  C:>set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\MINC\bin

  C:>mincinfo image.mnc
```

But I want to run it in a single line. So i tried this as

```
  C:>set path=%path%;"C:\Program Files\MINC\bin" && mincinfo image.mnc
```

But it gives the following error,

```
'mincinfo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

 operable program or batch file.
```

Is there something wrong in my commands? Please help to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can of course specify the full path of the program to execute, without needing to add it to the `PATH` variable.

```
C:>"C:\Program Files\MINC\bin\mincinfo" image.mnc
```

Comment: But it gives as not recognised as  follows  'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

if you concatenate your commands with &&, the whole line will be parsed at one time.
The result is, the path is yet the old path for the second command.

Comment: Is it..? Then is there any other way to do this in a single line command